# Where can I find good sources (textbook, lecture notes, etc) on multi-armed bandits?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, multi-armed-bandits

I am looking for good sources (textbook, lecture notes, etc)
on multi-armed bandits where both theory and practical examples are given.

I will be happy for suggestion of such material.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [bandit book](https://tor-lattimore.com/downloads/book/book.pdf) by Lattimore and Szepesvari, which is, I think, the main reference in the field: you can find pretty everything about Bandits, even more recent and research oriented topics.

Keep in main that it is a strongly theoretical book.

***Update***

- [RL: an introduction](https://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html) by Sutton & Barto: the chapter 2 is about *multi-armed bandits*. It's still theoretical but with some pseudo-code example, also the authors provides some bibliography.
- [Mastering RL with Python](https://www.packtpub.com/product/mastering-reinforcement-learning-with-python/9781838644147): see chapter 2 (MAB) and chapter 3 (contextual bandits). This is a practical book, with code examples in Python. Also you can find the code [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Reinforcement-Learning-with-Python).

Comment: I know this but it is too mathematical.

Comment: @DSPinfinity I can't blame you. I'll see if I can find something easier